# Get realtime data from DeepFace Stream function

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, face-recognition, deepface, retinanet

I have successfully tested the *stream* function from DeepFace library to get real time face detection and analysis data from my webcam. I call this method:

```
from deepface import DeepFace

DeepFace.stream(db_path = "C:/User/Sefik/Desktop/database")
```

It works well and displays crucial data such as face recognized, emotions etc... I would like to use the data it displays in my code but I don't know how to retreive it, something like:

```
from deepface import DeepFace

otp = DeepFace.stream(db_path = "C:/User/Sefik/Desktop/database")
otp['is_there_any_face'], otp['face_recognizedì], otp['emotions_detected']
```

Is there any function to retreive these data on my code? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream function is not for this purpose. You need to customize the source code if you want to store something from displays.

Identity is found in [this line](https://github.com/serengil/deepface/blob/master/deepface/commons/realtime.py#L425) and facial attributes are found in [this line](https://github.com/serengil/deepface/blob/master/deepface/commons/realtime.py#L185). You can save the values of these variables into a csv or whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you. Since you are better into the code than me, where is the line related to face recnognition?

Comment: It is stored in "label" variable. I shared the links in my main post. Please follow the first one.